# Logback-spring.xml with springProfile not working with multiple profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I am having multiple profiles in spring boot app and trying to use 3 different appenders.

1. CONSOLE appender
2. CONSOLE-GVA appender
3. FILE appender

when I am running this with "local" profile to test, then it uses "file" and "console" appender both.
I am expecting it should use the only File appender

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

<springProperty scope="context" name="maskedProperty" source="gva.logs.masked.property"/>

<springProfile name="!vsi, gva-gaia, !local">

    <appender name="CONSOLE-GVA" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.batch.logger.MaskingPatternLayout">
                <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
                <patternsProperty>${maskedProperty}</patternsProperty>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE-GVA"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="!vsi,!gva-gaia,!local">
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="vsi,local">

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.batch.logger.MaskingPatternLayout">
                <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
                <patternsProperty>${maskedProperty}</patternsProperty>
            </layout>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/batch.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the profileNames list size is larger than 1,As long as there is a match means success.
local dev matches !vsi.
org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringProfileAction#acceptsProfiles(InterpretationContext ic, Attributes attributes)

```
<springProfile name="!local">
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>
```